# GMSMapView: how to manage memory?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

My app is using a GMSMapView in a subview, and memory usage is as follows:

- 1.25 MB before map access;
- 21.5 MB after first map access;
- 30 MB (and sometimes spiking above 30) after zooming in and panning

No leaks, as far as I can tell with Instruments. The problem is, I am getting memory warnings, and often app shutdowns. Clearly, GoogleMaps is using the lion share of the app's memory. How can I release some of that in didReceiveMemoryWarning()?

Is it possible to have Google Maps in an app and manage its memory use, at least enough to prevent it from causing memory shutdowns?

This is GoogleMaps-iOS-1.3.0.

Update:

My memory figures were way off (was using Allocations Instrument instead of Activity Monitor). Here are the correct values:

- 8.8 MB before map access
- 57 MB after first map access
- 65 MB, with spikes near 80 MB. after zooming and panning

This is clearly in the "trouble" range for a 256 MB RAM device (iPod Touch 4G, e.g.), and explains the memory warnings and occasional kicks.

Is anybody out there successfully running Google Maps in an app on a 256 MB device?

Comment: Try to call stopRendering when the map is not on screen. This will release memory resources.

Comment: But what to do when a user is scrolling and zooming, and the warnings start coming (and sometimes, shutdown)? I.e., there's no opportunity to stop rendering.Basically, does the app just have to let the GMSMap drive it into memory bankruptcy? :-)

Comment: @user2444264 did u find any solution ,i am facing the same issue

Comment: No. There are outstanding bugs in Google Maps for iOS (see http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5202 for instance), so I reluctantly switched back to MapKit.

Comment: @user2444264 mapkit has the same problems

Comment: @user2444264 did you found solution for this? or MapKit working fire?

Answer (score 11):

Try to use this code in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated] ;
    [m_mapView clear];
    [m_mapView stopRendering] ;
    [m_mapView removeFromSuperview] ;
    m_mapView = nil ;
}
```

I tried this and it does free up some `GMSMapView` memory .

Comment: I use Swift so I'm not familiar with Obj-C but I would suggest calling this in a deinit function not viewWillDisappear.

Comment: @Rogoon I'm not so familiar with Swift, but I know that  `viewWillDisappear()` is used in exact the same way there as in Obj-C, so I see no point to place it elsewhere.

Comment: @turingtested Sounds like a fair point. Honestly, I don't exactly remember why I suggested that. I recall having some weird issues where viewWillDisappear was called when I didn't want it. Might have been when pushing a view on top of the current map. The map was getting removed and wasn't set back up when I returned to the mapview. Perhaps I just wasn't using viewWillAppear to reinit the map correctly at the time.

Comment: its reducing little bit of size only when the viewWillDisappear called after . Once the map view load once again the memory size was increased double.! what should i do if i maintain the memory as constant.

Comment: It reduced my CPU Usage by 40%. Stopped creating tons of Google map vector tile threads. :)

Comment: `stopRendering` should no longer be used. It is deprecated with the following message :  "This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future release."

Answer (score 7):

The maps API uses tiles which are 256 x 256 pixels in size. These are loaded into memory as 32 bits-per-pixel textures, so they will use 256 x 256 x 4 = 256kb per tile.

If you have an iPad which is 1024 x 768, then you'll need 4 x 3 = 12 tiles = 3MB. However this is only if your view happens to be perfectly aligned to tile boundaries - in practise it will cross boundaries, and so you'll probably need 5 x 4 = 20 tiles = 5MB.

However if you zoom out to almost the point at which the next lower zoom level would be displayed, each tile will be drawn at just over half its full size, and so you'll need 10 x 8 = 80 tiles = 20MB.

Then if you have a Retina device it will actually load the next higher zoom level's tiles and therefore require twice as many of them in each dimension (to match the screen's pixels not points), and so you'll need 20 x 16 = 320 tiles = 80MB.

Similar calculations for an iPhone 5 work out to 240 tiles = 60MB.

So, if you calculate the amount of memory which the map requires just for the tiles, not counting any overheads or other memory used for internal processing, it works out to quite a lot. So there's possibly nothing you can do. The maps SDK already frees unused tiles when there is memory pressure - but it can't free tiles which are required to render the current view.

That means your only option may be to reduce memory usage in your own code.

For my app I had to change the way it worked on an iPad 1, because it was running out of memory and crashing very often. For other devices I found it worked okay.

Some ideas for possible workarounds might be to reduce the size of the map view, or snap the zoom level to an integral value. Neither would be great for the user, but they might help avoid a crash.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. You say, "The maps SDK already frees unused tiles when there is memory pressure". I don't see any dips in memory usage in response to memory warnings.  I've been testing this on a (256 MB ram) iPod Touch 4G, and think that you are right that it just won't make it unless I reduce the screen size.

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure, but in my app I handle memory warnings by releasing as much memory as I can, but if the SDK wasn't also releasing tiles when possible, then my app would be crashing very regularly :) So I assume it's releasing tiles when it can, but there's a limit to how far it can go, which still works out to quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have two mapViews in two View Controllers back to back so I popped View Controller and remove map view from superview.

```
override func onBtnBack() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.mapView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also stucked with huge memory used by GMSMapview. This is serious issue within google map sdk and i think Google team working on it.
They also Fixed some memory reclamation issues in version 1.9.0
Other ways to reduce memory by-

1. Reduce the size of GMSMapView as small as possible
2. Use latest Version 1.9.0 - as on October 2014.

Use following link to download latest sdk-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases